# when to use and how to write loop and a half code

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

When do we use loop and a half? Also, should someone briefly elaborate how to write its code?

Comment: What do you even *mean* by "loop and a half"? I've never heard of the term before.

Comment: I googled "loop and a half" (which I didn't know either), and came up with this: http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/patterns/plopd/loops.html#loop-and-a-half, which explains what it is and when we use it. Google is your best friend.

Comment: It seems someone puts a `break` in the middle of a loop and named it "loop and a half."

Comment: I think the OP is about loop-and-a-half problem described in [this note](http://www.cis.temple.edu/~giorgio/cis71/software/roberts/documents/loopexit.txt).

Comment: Loop-and-a-Half Repetition Control, that's what's written in the book :/ Thanks dasblinkenlight :)

Answer (score 12):

You use loop-and-a-half to avoid repeating code from outside the loop to the inside.  Example:

```
read a;
while a != b do
  stuff;
  read a;
end
```

becomes

```
while true do
  read a
  if a == b then break
  stuff;
end
```

Now I only have the read in one place.

Comment: @Alexander that's how I would write the code normally.  Its better to create a sub to avoid repeating code.  But I do run into the loop and a half pattern fairly often.

Comment: @Alexander That can't assign a new value to a (in Java that is), so that's probably not much of a help in real examples where stuff will probably want to access a.

Comment: @Voo, [really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) - anyways this most voted answer is not even Java though.

Comment: @stark, that'd may be a `goto` tendency.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah there's a **big** difference between changing internal state of an object and assigning a new object to a variable (yes I was quite careful when writing that sentence). Yes you can get around the limitation by creating wrapper objects, but that's not especially nice and only works if you control the whole stack - otherwise you also have to write lots of wrapper methods that take your wrapper objects to the real method and then change its state on return.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, I'd like to add that the scope of the variable (assuming `a` is a local variable in this idiom) is minimized as compared to the alternative case, where `a` is still in scope even after the while loop terminates. Minimizing the scope of local variables is considered good practice whenever possible (Josh Bloch, Effective Java, Item 45).