# Infinite loop inside 'do_select' function of Linux kernel

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel

I am surprised that Linux kernel has infinite loop in 'do_select' function implementation. Is it normal practice?

Also I am interested in how file changes monitoring implemented in Linux kernel? Is it infinite loop again?

[select.c source code](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9/fs/select.c)

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.  Your second question is not one you can expect to get answered here: try #kernelnewbies instead.

Comment: FYI and In my opinion there are lots and lots examples of infinite while loops. How would you check for events without it?

Comment: @zwol thanks, I will consider that in future.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an infinite loop; that term is reserved for loops with no exit condition *at all*.  This loop has its exit condition in the *middle*: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9/fs/select.c#L482  This is a very common idiom in C.  It's called "loop and a half" and there's a simple pseudocode example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10767975/388520 which clearly illustrates why you would want to do this.  (That question talks about Java but that's not important; this is a general structured-programming idiom.)

I'm not a kernel expert, but this particular loop appears to have been written this way because the logic of the *inner* loop needs to run both before and after the call to `poll_schedule_timeout` at the very bottom of the outer loop.  That code is checking whether there are any events to return; if there are *already* events to return when `select` is invoked, it's supposed to return immediately; if there aren't any initially, there will be when `poll_schedule_timeout` returns.  So in normal operation the outer loop should cycle either 0.5 or 1.5 times.  (There may be edge-case circumstances where the outer loop cycles more times than that.)  I might have chosen to pull the inner loop out to its own function, but that might involve passing pointers to too many local variables around.

This is also not a *spin* loop, by which I mean, the CPU is not wasting electricity checking for events over and over again until one happens.  If there are no events to report when control reaches the call to `poll_schedule_timeout`, that function (by, ultimately, calling [`__schedule`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.9/kernel/sched/core.c#L2838)) will cause the calling thread to *block* -- the CPU is taken away from that thread and assigned to another process that can do something useful with it.  (If there are *no* processes that need the CPU, it'll be put into a low-power "halt" until the next interrupt fires.)  When one of the events happens, or the timeout, the thread that called `select` will get "woken up" and `poll_schedule_timeout` will return.

On a larger note, operating system kernels often do things that would be considered strange, poor style, or even flat-out wrong, in the service of other engineering goals (efficiency, code reuse, avoidance of race conditions that can only occur on some CPUs, ...)  They are written by people who know *exactly* what they are doing and *exactly* how far they can get away with bending the rules.  You can learn a lot from reading though OS code, but you probably shouldn't try to *imitate* it until you have a bit more experience.  You wouldn't try to pastiche the style of James Joyce as your first exercise in creative writing, ne?  Same deal.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that exit condition. Moreover it has timeout value as argument to interrupt execution. But theoretically exit condition can never happen and timeout value can be big enough.

Comment: I suppose that it is not very efficient to infinitely check all files. I thought that there is must be another more efficient way.